# How to define an environment that defines a macro, maybe a brace-parenthesis issue?

Tags: macros, environments, grouping

I know how to define a macro as follows

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}{ here my macro commands }
```

But I would like to create an environment that defines macro, as follows

```
 \begin{definemycommand}{\mycommand}
  here my macro coomands
 \end{definemycommand}
```

so that the result is the same.

I tried something very silly like

```
 \newenvironment{definemycommand}[1]{\newcommand{#1}\{ }{ \} }
```

or

```
 \newenvironment{definemycommand}[1]{\newcommand{#1}{ }{ } }
```

but clearly this does not work because "{" and "}" are not recognised as I would like. I suspect that there is a *right* way to do that.

Comment: environments form a local group (that is the whole point of them) so any definitions inside the environment will end at the end of the environment. It is possible to define global definitions but latex has no syntax for that. You have to drop to primitive tex so would be odd to add to an environment syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to escape the braces for this kind of use as in:

```latex
\newenvironment{definemycommand}[1]{\newcommand{#1}\{ }{ \} }
```

so, let's look at your second attempt:

```latex
\newenvironment{definemycommand}[1]{\newcommand{#1}{ }{ } }
```

This is not correct, because `\newcommand` doesn't take that many arguments (the second `{ }` would be left in the input stream, followed by a probably unwanted space token). Worse, `\newenvironment` requires *two arguments* in curly braces after the square-bracketed number of arguments: one for the start, one for the end.

## Local definition

`\newcommand` performs a local definition, so with the following, you can't use `\mycommand` outside the environment:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{definemycommand}[1]
  {\newcommand{#1}{here my macro commands}}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{definemycommand}{\mycommand}
  \mycommand
\end{definemycommand}

%\mycommand                      % ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Global definition

If you want to be able to use the command also after the environment has ended, you can use `\gdef`. But there is a notable difference with `\newcommand` (among others): `\gdef` doesn't check if the command already exists. It would thus overwrite an existing command of the same name without notice. If you don't want this, you can use `\ifdefined ... \fi` or `\ifcsname ... \endcsname ... \fi` (optional `\else` in each case).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{definemycommand}[1]
  {\gdef#1{here my macro commands}}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{definemycommand}{\mycommand}
  \mycommand
\end{definemycommand}

\bigskip
\mycommand                      % no problem

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Using the environment body for the macro replacement text

In case you want to use the environment body for the macro replacement text, you can do as in [Phelype Oleinik's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540251/73317) or use the `environ` package. I use `\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}` in order to expand the special `\BODY` macro exactly once (the macro is defined by `\NewEnviron` from the `environ` package).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{definemycommand}[1]
  {\xdef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{definemycommand}{\mycommand}
  here my macro commands
\end{definemycommand}

\mycommand

\end{document}
```

Same output as in the first example:

[image]

Beware of possible spaces at the beginning and end of the environment body. Use tests such as `X\mycommand X`, `\show\mycommand` or `\meaning\mycommand` to check the precise behavior or definition of the command your `definemycommand` environment defines. In this case, the `environ` package appears to remove the spaces by default, so this potential pitfall doesn't apply.

## Refinements using `etoolbox`

Here is a variant of the previous code that:

- takes the command name as argument *without the leading backslash* (I use `etoolbox`'s `\csxdef`, which internally relies on `\csname ... \endcsname` and `\xdef`);
- prints an error message if the command is already defined (this uses `\ifcsdef` to perform the test; of course, if you want to be able to redefine the command, simply remove the `\ifcsdef` test and the `\errmessage` call);
- uses `etoolbox`'s `\expandonce{...}` command as syntactic sugar for `\unexpanded\expandafter{...}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\NewEnviron{definemycommand}[1]
  {%
    \ifcsdef{#1}
      {\errmessage{%
         Command \expandafter\string\csname#1\endcsname\space already defined}%
      }
      {\csxdef{#1}{\expandonce{\BODY}}}%
  }
  {}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\whatever}{foo bar}

\begin{definemycommand}{mycommand}
  \whatever\space here my macro commands
\end{definemycommand}

\show\mycommand                 % ->\whatever \space here my macro commands.
X\mycommand X

% ERROR: Command \mycommand already defined.
% \begin{definemycommand}{mycommand}
%   here my macro commands
% \end{definemycommand}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The output of `\show\mycommand`, namely:

```latex
> \mycommand=macro:
->\whatever \space here my macro commands.
```

proves that macros used in the environment body aren't expanded at the time the macro (e.g., `\mycommand`) is defined. That is precisely the purpose of the `\unexpanded` from the example without `etoolbox`, or `\expandonce` in this example. Such macros given in the environment body will be expanded later, when `\mycommand` is expanded several times (presumably as part of typesetting, but this really depends on where and how you'll use it). This is often a desirable property, which is why I implemented things this way (otherwise, a simple `\xdef` or `\csxdef` does the job).

Comment: I just made some quick test, but your last code seems to work very well!

Comment: I added  another example that allows a different syntax, checks whether the command already exists and prints an error message if this is the case (see *Refinements using etoolbox*).

Answer (score 3):

Using `xparse`'s `b` argument type to grab the body of an environment:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{definemycommand}{mb}
  {\gdef#1{#2}}% #1 is the macro name, and #2 is the env body
  {}
\begin{document}

\begin{definemycommand}{\test}
  here my macro coomands
\end{definemycommand}

\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Note that you have to use `\gdef` (or something like that), otherwise the definition is lost when the environment ends.

Comment: yes true but the resulting syntax is rather weird:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Defining `\gnewcommand` is left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: I just cut and pasted your code but I get "ERROR: LaTeX error: "xparse/unknown-argument-type"

--- TeX said ---
! 
! Unknown argument type 'b' for the command '\environment definemycommand'."

Comment: @user126154 The `b` argument type was introduced about a year ago, so you need TeXLive 2019 at least (or update MiKTeX, if you use that) to be able to use `b`. But the principle is pretty much the same as the `\BODY` thing in frougon's answer, so you can accept his answer instead

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what this would be useful for. Anyway, here's how you can do it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g__definecommand_temp_tl

\NewDocumentEnvironment{definecommand}{mO{0}o+b}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g__definecommand_temp_tl { \newcommand{#1}[#2]{#4} }
   }
   {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g__definecommand_temp_tl { \newcommand{#1}[#2][#3]{#4} }
   }
  \group_insert_after:N \g__definecommand_temp_tl
 }
 {}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{definecommand}{\fooA}
  this has no arguments
\end{definecommand}

\begin{definecommand}{\fooB}[1]
  this has one argument #1
\end{definecommand}

\begin{definecommand}{\fooC}[2][foo]
  this has one mandatory argument #2 and an optional argument #1
\end{definecommand}

.\fooA.

.\fooB{xyz}.

.\fooC{uvw}.

.\fooC[x]{uvw}.

\end{document}
```

[image]